# How do I calculate the damage of a Wild-Shaped Giant Squid with Powerful Shape and Strong Jaw?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, damage, wild-shape

What would the damage be for a 10th level druid with Powerful Shape and Strong Jaw active when Wildshaping into a giant squid?

**Strong Jaw:**

> Each natural attack that creature makes deals damage as if the
>   creature were two sizes larger than it actually is. If the creature is
>   already Gargantuan or Colossal-sized, double the amount of damage
>   dealt by each of its natural attacks instead. This spell does not
>   actually change the creature’s size; all of its statistics except the
>   amount of damage dealt by its natural attacks remain unchanged.

**Powerful Shape:**

> When in wild shape, treat your size as one category
>   larger for the purpose of calculating CMB, CMD, carrying capacity, and
>   any size-based special attacks you use or that are used against you
>   (such as grab, swallow whole, and trample).

**Giant Squid (huge):**

> Bite +14 (2d6+7),
>   2 Arms +14 (1d6+7),
>   Tentacles +12 (4d6+3/19-20 plus grab) -- vs Huge or Smaller only
>   Constrict (4d6+10)

I believe the new stats would be...
**Giant Squid (Colossal)**:

> Bite +16 (4d6+7) 
>   2 Arms +16 (2d6+7),
>   Tentacles +14 (8d6+3/19-20 plus grab) -- vs Gargantuan or smaller only
>   Constrict (8d6+10)

Additional Question: Does Strong Jaw apply to every natural attack when wildshaping, or only one specific attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Increase the damage dice for all natural weapons.

First let's address the *[Strong Jaw](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/strong-jaw/)* spell. It increases the damage rolls of each of your natural weapons. To address your secondary question, re-read the beginning of the spell's text:

> Each natural attack that creature makes...

Fortunately the spell description contains a table that shows the new damage values for your natural weapons. The [giant squid](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/squid/giant-squid/)'s normal size is Huge, and 2 sizes larger is Colossal. So the damage dice change as follows:

- 2d6 (bite) increases to 4d6.
- 1d6 (arms) has no match in the Huge column, so instead find any 1d6 and move two spaces right, which gives you 2d6.
- 4d6 (tentacles) is considered Colossal size on the chart, so you double it to 8d6. Since the giant squid uses tentacles for its [constrict](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Constrict_Ex) ability, you also increase the constrict damage dice.

#### 2. Increase CMB and CMD by +1.

Next is the [Powerful Shape](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/powerful-shape/) feat. This effectively adds +1 to your CMB and CMD, but does not actually benefit your attack or damage rolls. For the giant squid, you add this bonus to your grapple check when using grab.

This also means you count as one size larger (Gargantuan) for the purpose of the [grab](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Grab-Ex-) ability, which you can now use against Gargantuan or smaller creatures!

> Unless otherwise noted, grab can only be used against targets of a size equal to or smaller than the creature with this ability.

Note that the giant squid has the grab ability for its tentacles, which can be a secondary natural weapon. When you use [Wild Shape](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/#Wild_Shape_Su), you don't gain the creature's feats, so you don't gain [Multiattack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-feats#multiattack). If you use tentacles as a secondary attack, the resulting grab check could still be at a -5 penalty.

---

Using the druid's BAB and the adjusted Strength modifier (STR), the offense statistics would be calculated based on which attacks or maneuvers you use. Note that these formulas may be adjusted by other miscellaneous bonuses or penalties.

When making primary natural attacks, or using a standard action to attack or initiate a  [grapple](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple), you use the following:

- Attack roll = d20 + BAB + STR - 2 (size)
- Bite damage roll = 4d6 + STR
- Arms damage roll = 2d6 + STR
- Tentacles damage roll = 8d6 + STR
- Grapple maneuver = d20 + BAB + STR + 2 (size) + 4 (grab) + 1
- Other maneuvers = d20 + BAB + STR + 2 (size) + 1
- Constrict damage roll = 8d6 + \$\lfloor\$STR*3/2\$\rfloor\$

If you make a full attack, then your tentacles are a secondary natural weapon, and you use the following instead for your tentacles:

- Attack roll = d20 + BAB + STR - 2 (size) - 5
- Grab grapple check = d20 + BAB + STR + 2 (size) + 4 (grab) + 1 - 5
- Damage roll = 8d6 + \$\lfloor\$STR*1/2\$\rfloor\$

Comment: Might be worth it to note why you didn't increase the damage by another size category as per Powerful Shape (effective size increases don't stack)